# Request.IsAuthenticated was false while the server was being redirected to the another server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, load-balancing, session-state

My application runs on load balancer and I have 2 servers. The application is installed on both servers. If Server1 crashes, the application will run on Server2.

While being redirected to the other server, I want `Request.IsAuthenticated` to be true and keep working. However, `Request.IsAuthenticated` was false while the server was being redirected to the another server.

I am using SQL Server session state to ensure the continuity of session data.

I added the following part to `web.config` for the machine key values of 2 servers to be the same.

```
<machineKey validationKey='C44B8B7C521CB5BC7E602BAE6118AA44CD690C7304817129DA27C17E800132A1BD946C6D9AD12F0A5B342840C7D130564195428160B7466146938CA9E3A62686'   decryptionKey='0E9DF2DA7F210B84087690FF0BF25C905182AD81E16A5FA9' validation='SHA1'/>
```

I configured session state in `web.config` like this:

```
<sessionState cookieName="myCookieName" mode="SQLServer" 
        sqlConnectionString="..." cookieless="false" 
        regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="30" />
```

It didn't work.

Why is `Request.IsAuthenticated` false? How can I keep status of authentication?

Comment: "didn't work" means what? What precise problem occurred? Did the relevant database actually get created? What do you mean by "the server was being redirected to the other server". Load balancing doesn't work by redirecting "from" one server to the other. The load balancer sits "in front" of the two servers (conceptually) and decides which one to forward each individual request to. If the request contains a session ID and you have shared session state between each instance of the application on different servers then everything should be fine.

Comment: Setting the machineKeys is not required for this to work AFAIK.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx has a good guide on setting it up.

Comment: It kind of depends on how your load balancer is set up. If it's directing a pre-authenticated request to server A and discovers it's down, then hypothetically it should be replaying the request to Server B, cooking and header and all. If however Server A is responding with a redirect, then that redirect wouldn't necessarily be authenticated. So. How is Server A actually responding (if at all) when it goes down? What happens to the cookies/header?

Comment: The application runs on two servers and the load balancer sits in front of the two servers. There is no problem here. A spesific user logged in the application over ServerA. When this user is working in the application, I restarted the ServerA and refreshed the browser. The load balancer tried to run from ServerB but Request.IsAuthenticated was false. Therefore the user was redirected to login screen again. How can I configure it so that it is not false.